# Suppose that every subsequence of $X=x_{n}$ has a subsequence converge to $0$ show that $\lim X=0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

Please check my proof

Suppose we have every subsequence $x_{n}$ converge to $0$

We have

\begin{align}x_{1}:&\; |x_{1}-0|<\frac{\epsilon }{n} \\
x_{2}:&\; |x_{2}-0|<\frac{\epsilon }{n} \\
x_{3}:&\; |x_{3}-0|<\frac{\epsilon }{n} \\
&\vdots\\
x_{n}:&\; |x_{n}-0|<\frac{\epsilon }{n} \end{align}

then 
$|x_{1}-0|+|x_{2}-0|+|x_{3}-0|+....|x_{n}-0| <\frac{\epsilon }{n}+\frac{\epsilon }{n}....+\frac{\epsilon }{n}=\epsilon $

therefore $\lim X = 0$

Comment: Having "a" convergent subsequence is not equivalent to having "every" subsequence converging to zero ...

Comment: I don't actually get the proof, which might be partially because of the notation. Can you please use a bit more words for what your reasoning is?

Comment: To elaborate on @Math-fun's comment: And if we had the latter, then the exercise would be trivial, since $(x_n)_n$ is itself a subsequence of $(x_n)_n$...

Comment: I suggest a proof by contradiction instead. Assume that $X$ does not converge to zero and construct a subsequence that has no subsequence which comnverges to zero.

Comment: anyone could show correct proof ,please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Your proof is incorrect.** Saying that *every subsequence has a subsequence converging to $0$* is not the same as *every subsequence has every of its subsequences converging to $0$*. But you appear to be using the former, leading to a flawed argument.

*Here is an outline of a correct proof. Place your mouse over the hidden text areas to reveal their contents (i.e., a more detailed argument).*

1). Show that $(x_n)_n$ is bounded.

> By contradiction: assume it is not. Then, for every $M>0$ and $N>0$ there exists $n\geq N$ such that $\lvert x_n\rvert \geq M$. In particular, this allows us to extract a subsequence $(x_{\varphi(n)})_n$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\lvert x_{\varphi(n)}\rvert = \infty$. But this subsequence then does not have a subsequence converging to $0$, contradiction.

2). Use the fact that a bounded sequence converges if, and only if, it only has one limit point. To do that, take any limit point $\ell$ of $(x_n)_n$ (we know that there exists at least one, since $(x_n)_n$ is bounded), and show that necessarily $\ell=0$.

> Let $\ell$ be a limit point: by definition, there exists a subsequence of $(x_n)_n$ converging to $\ell$. Now this subsequence itself has, by hypothesis, a subsequence converging to $0$. *But* it also converges to $\ell$, since it's a subsequence of something converging to $\ell$: by uniqueness of the limit, $\ell=0$. Therefore, $0$ is the only limit point of $(x_n)_n$, meaning that $(x_n)_n$ converges to $0$.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: Sir what if $(x_{\varphi(n)})_n$ is sequence $(1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0....)$? This sequence has limit infinity but has subsequence which converges to $0$. Please reply.

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi the statement says that is **every subsequence has a subsequence converging to 0** then the sequence converges to 0. In your example, this is not the case. Which subsequence of $(1,2,3,4,...)$ converges to 0? (Basically, you are forgetting the quantifier "every").